# Manging state of functional components with useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assume I have an App.jsx:

**App.jsx**

```js
const App = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <NavBar />
            <BooksList />
            <TextEditor />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default App;
```

The `BooksList` and `TextEditor` are 2 functional components. In one component, I have the ability to save the contents of an editor to a database:

**Editor.jsx**

```js
const TextEditor = () => {
    return(
        <*editor related stuff*>
    )
}

const SaveContent = ({ value, icon }) => {
    return (
        <SaveButton
            onMouseDown={async () => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
                const response = await fetch('/add_book', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },

                    body: JSON.stringify(value)

                })

                if (response.ok) {
                    console.log('response okay')
                }
            }}
        >
            <Icon icon={icon}></Icon>
        </SaveButton>
    )
}
```

And this successful writes to my DB.

I want to have the BookList component automatically update with the contents of the database as I save/delete items. Here is BookList component I have so far:

**BooksList.jsx**

```js
const BooksList = () => {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/get_books')
        .then(response => 
            response.json()
        .then(data => {
            setBooks(data)
        })
        );
    }, [])

    return (
        <*list of saved editors*>
    )
}
```

So on load, if the DB is empty, it shows nothing. When I save to the DB, it shows nothing, then when I refresh the page, it shows me the data I want to get back. I want to be able to save the data and see the above component refresh and update automatically.

I'm new to React and JS, so any pointers would be great. I think it may need a rewrite to use class based components for easier management of state? But I am unsure. My basic understanding is that `useEffect()` is the functional equivalent of class based mounting methods. Which leads me to believe that this can be done. However, I have read that stateful components should use class based components.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few different ways to about doing this and it all depends on how your components are structured. The bottom line is, when you successfully POST to the database, you need to trigger your GET request. A quick, dirty solution would be to just move the GET request out to a separate function and call it within the useEffect and pass the function down as a prop. Something like this:

**Editor.jsx**

```
const SaveContent = ({ value, icon, refreshBooksList }) => {
    const addBook = useCallback(async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/add_book', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify(value)

        })

        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('response okay')
            refreshBooksList()
        }
    }, [value, refreshBooksList])

    return (
        <SaveButton
            onMouseDown={addBook}
        >
            <Icon icon={icon}></Icon>
        </SaveButton>
    )
}
```

**BooksList.jsx**

```
const BooksList = () => {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

    const getBooksList = useCallback(async () => {
        await fetch('/get_books')
            .then(response => 
                response.json()
            .then(data => {
                setBooks(data)
            })
        );
    }, [setBooks])

    useEffect(() => {
        getBooksList()
    }, [])

    return (
        <*list of saved editors*>
    )
}
```

If the two components are not parent/child, then you need to move the `getBooks` function up the tree to the shared parent.

Depending on what the API returns, you may be able to remove the additional GET request altogether and simply update the state. If that's the case, you could look at using React Context instead to avoid passing props around.

Comment: Both of these components are children of an `App.jsx` components. So that means i have to move the `getBooksList()` up to `App.jsx` and then pass the function to `BookList.jsx` as a prop to be called by `useEffect`? Ill update the question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why this is a "quick and dirty" solution? If there is something I can do that is better that you can think of, let met know!

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Move the `getBooksList` up to `App.jsx` and pass it down to your two components via props. I'd only suggest this is quick and dirty due to the additional network requests you have to make.

Comment: Just to clarify, should `refreshBooksList` from  `Editor.jsx` actually be `getBooksList` as per your example?

Comment: As the post is now posting nothing to the DB, but i feel like that is a separate issue as the auto update is working correctly! So if you have anything, that would be great. The only difference between the 2 implementation is the `useCallback` in `SaveContent()` function.

Comment: Sorry for the multi message, but i removed the `useCallback()` and called the `async`  directly in `onMouseDown` and it works correctly. If you could explain why that would be great.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a bad code sample on my part. The `value` prop should have been added to the `useCallback()` dependencies. I've updated my sample appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If your Editor and BookList components are inside the same parent component, then you can use a state inside the Parent component. Parent will pass a callback to Editor. Editor will use this callback to notify Parent that there is a new book. Parent will increment the state and will pass that state to BookList as a props. Then BookList will check that props has changed in useEffect and reload the list of books.

Here is a minimal code example:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(0);
  const onNewBook = () => {
    setX(state => state+1);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <BookList x={X} />
      <Editor onNewBook={onNewBook} />
    </>
  )
}

const Editor = (props) => {
  onSave = () => {
    // Save the editor to the DB
    props.onNewBook();
  }
}

const BookList= (props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Reload the list from DB
  }, [props.X])
}
```

Comment: Hey just to clarify, i update the question with the parent App.jsx. Thanks for the contribution. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If Editor and BookList are not inside the same Parent component, you can use events to communicate between Editor and BookList. Editor can send events and BookList can listen to these events.

**BookList**

```
document.body.addEventListener('updateBookList', onUpdateBookList, false);
```

**Editor**

```
const myEvent = new CustomEvent('updateBookList');
document.body.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```